# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "shieldbow". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

So I'm trying to import an npm library to use it on a web app. But when I try to import it, it gives me the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "shieldbow". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

with the code

```
import { Client } from 'shieldbow';
```

If I change the module specifier to the node_modules folder, I get another error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../../node_modules/shieldbow/dist/index' does not provide an export named 'Client'
```

with the code

```
import { Client } from '../../node_modules/shieldbow/dist/index';
```

If was told it was because it is loading on client-side, but I have no idea how to do it on server-side. Any advide?

Comment: It appears everything is correct - can you verify that the module is listed in your package.json? Run `npm i shieldbow` just to be sure.

Comment: How do you build your application? You have to use a bundler like vite or we pack to be able to use npm packages.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Yes, I have verified that the module is listed in the package.son, and when building my application with vite, the error still appears.